# How to make a really long text wrap to keep it in a table td using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables, word-wrap

How can I make sure `10,000` characters will fit in a `<td>` and not overflow?

I have tried multiple things like:

- `word-wrap: break-word`
- `overflow-wrap`
- `white-space: initial`

...and few more, but nothing seems to work:

```css
.a {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 250px; 
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

table,
th,
td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="5">
        SOME STUFF
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A-text</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>C-text</div>
      </td>  
      <td>
        <div>C</div>
        <div>C-text</div>
      </td>        
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8">
        <div class="a">
        
abcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedf12345678910
        
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to `nowrap`, which prevents the text from wrapping across multiple lines:

> **`nowrap`**
>
> Collapses whitespace as for `normal`, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within the source.

You need to add both `word-break: break-word` and `white-space: normal` (or just remove this property, as `normal` is its default value) to make the text fit in the cell:

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.a {
  width: 300px; 
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background: yellow;
  
  /* Just to keep text selection hightlight inside the table: */
  overflow: hidden;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

th,
td {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  
    <tr>
      <td>
        SOME STUFF
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A-text</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>B</div>
        <div>C-text</div>
      </td>  
      <td>
        <div>C</div>
        <div>C-text</div>
      </td>        
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">
        <div class="a">
        
abcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcedf12345678910
        
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, have been stuck on this for a while.